# Cocoa left list with bubbled count numbers

Tags: list, cocoa, categories

What I'm looking for is a Cocoa component with left tableview where you have groups(categories) with number of items inside rounded bubble. 
I've seen that kind of view in a few apps recently.

Is it some kind of Cocoa component or I have to do that customly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're referring to what Apple calls a "source list" or "source view".  See the [SourceView sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Okay but this does not have a bubble with item count. I've just read about Sidebar component. Maybe it has some kind of bubble with an item count?

Comment: You can use a rounded button to provide the "bubble". If you're referring to Apple's [SidebarDemo sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html), then, yes, it illustrates that technique, too.

Comment: That's it but there are no + and - buttons to add new groups. Does Apple provides some kind of control for that too?